# Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce How to send info about products each have been loaded by Ajax?

Tags: e-commerce, analytics

Products display on a page according to google analytics Enhanced Ecommerce documentation. I have to run next script to sent info about that:

```
ga('ec:addImpression', {            // Provide product details in an impressionFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel/T-Shirts',   // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'Black',               // Product variant (string).
  'list': 'Search Results',         // Product list (string).
  'position': 1,                    // Product position (number).
  'dimension1': 'Member'            // Custom dimension (string).
});
ga('send', 'pageview'); // !!
```

And the page hit should be to sent with this info.

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

So, How to send info about products each have been loaded later by Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

All e-commerce data needs to be sent with either an (non-interactive or not) event or a pageview. In your case you might want to use a virtual pageview since you don't have actual pageviews. You could do something like this

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/your/ajax/page');
```

each time you load your Ajax content with you ecomm data.

Comment: If to use virtual pages then in statistics there will be not that page on which the product show

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get what you mean. VPVs are just like regular pageviews. The only difference being that you are (re)defining the page path. Can you elaborate on your concern?

Comment: When for that case I use a virtual page, target report will contain info about  shows info at the previous page instead actual.